# NodeJS cloudinary search API by context

Tags: node.js, axios, cloudinary

I'm able to get a list of all images/videos from my cloudinary using this

```
  const response = await axios.get('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/image', {
    auth: {
      username: 'xxx',
      password: 'xx'
    }
  })
```

But I want to get only images with the correct context, so I have two key value pairs I want to search by.

```
{month: "November"}
{year: "2020}
```

But I cant seem to figure out how to work it form their docs, its more so about downloading their widget to use which I don't want to and just use axios.

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api

It has the route listed as
`/resources/:resource_type/context/`

But if I try such as `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/image/context/month=November&year=2020`

I am getting an error

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Invalid value context for parameter type"
}
}
```

Comment: What about `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/image/context?month=November&year=2020` with `?`

Comment: Nope :/ gives empty result


{
"resources": []
}

I know I can search by a tag this way
`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/image/tags/November?2021`

Comment: I leave a new answer, you could take a look.

Comment: Hi, I found there is a way to search by multiple contexts, I add it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 20201117

I found there is a way to search by multiple contexts with search API.
You need to use `And` to combine the condition.
I've tried it, and it works.

```js
axios.post('https://<API_KEY>:<API_SECRET>@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/search', {
    "expression": "context.month=November AND context.year=2020"
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

#### Original Answer

You could use like this.
`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/image/context?key=month&value=November` with **only one key-value pair**.

Here is a template form documentation.
`curl https://<API_KEY>:<API_SECRET>@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/resources/video/context?mycontextkey&value=mycontextvalue`

But, in the documentation I didn't see there are multiple key-value pair in [Get Resource by Context](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources_by_context).

And in the nodejs SDK of cloudinary.
It just implement only one key-value pair, you could see it in [github](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/lib/api.js#L45)

```js
params.key = key;
if (value != null) {
    params.value = value;
}
return call_api("get", uri, params, callback, options);
```

And i think that search api might archive it.
But in the Expression Fields of [search api](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/search_api#expression_fields), it said.

> You can search for a specific key-value pair, or for all resources with a particular key regardless of the value, or with a particular value regardless of the key.

So, yes ... **only one specific key-value context** in search api.
But if you still want to try with search api, you could do this with `POST` method.

```
axios.post('https://<API_KEY>:<API_SECRET>@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/search', {
    "expression": "context.month=November"
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

I'm also confused why there are no multiple key-value pairs for context searching in cloudinary.
Then, I think you could convert you structure of context.

Original:

```
month=November
year=2020
```

Convert it to

```
date=2020-November
```

Then use it to do context searching in `GET` Method.
`curl https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/image/context?key=date&value=2020-November`

Or use expression with `POST` method like this.

```js
axios.post('https://<API_KEY>:<API_SECRET>@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name/resources/search', {
    "expression": "context.date=2020-November"
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
```